# How to represent multiple level combinations?

Tags: python, sympy

The book [Introduction to Probability](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Probability-Chapman-Statistical-Science/dp/1466575573) by Blitzstein and Hwang provides an example of combinations using ice cream.

- The first level is cone: **Waffle** or **Cake**
- The second level is flavour: **chocolate**, **vanilla** or **strawberry**

The basic example is `2 * 3 = 6` separate choices.

I can represent each level of choice separately:

```py
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC
from sympy.utilities.iterables import combinations, combinations_with_replacement

cones = combinations('CW', 1)
list(cones)
>>> [('C',), ('W',)]

flavours = combinations('cvs', 1)
list(flavours)
>>> [('c',), ('v',), ('s',)]

# how to get a list representing all choices? (Cc, Cv, Cs, Wc, Wv, Ws)

# how to return a count of the choices, e.g. with nC()?
```

I was wondering if it is possible to combine the levels with sympy and return a list of each combination and a count of the available combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is a **set multiplication**. eg., {A,B}*{1,2} -> {{A,1}, {A,2}, {B,1}, {B,2}). In python you do this with `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

allChoices = set(product(set('CW'), set('csv')))
allChoicesPretty = set(a+b for a, b in allChoices)
numberOfChoices = len(allChoices)

print(allChoices)
print(allChoicesPretty)
print(numberOfChoices)
```

output:

```
{('C', 'v'), ('W', 's'), ('W', 'c'), ('C', 'c'), ('C', 's'), ('W', 'v')}
{'Wv', 'Ws', 'Cs', 'Wc', 'Cc', 'Cv'}
6
```

Actually you don't need `sympy`at all for this, furthermore `cartes` is actually an alias to `iterable.product` [1]

**Comments**

In a `set` each element happens only once, and there is no order in `set`. If you need one of these or both, replace `set` by `list` and `{}` by `[]`. This might matter for instance in probability when you pick an object from a bag and put it back. But operations on sets are faster. A way to have multiple times the "same event" while using sets, is to add a tag, such as a number eg., A,A,A -> A1,A2,A3. This is very practical to think this way, because it's usually simpler to think about events (or compute probabilities) with tags and then remove the tags (equivalent to say "the order doesn't matter") when we do probabilities.

It's also related to the fact that in mathematics we can express (interpret, build) everything in **set theory** [2], which is actually needs few deductive elements of **proof theory** [4]; which is a way to build the foundations of mathematics (ZFC := Zermelo Fraenkel Choice). All mathematical proof happens inside ZFC, but it's almost never mentionned in the proof.

There are other ways to interpret all mathematics, such as **category theory** [3], which is closely related to computing langages. The third possible foundation I know is **homotopy type theory** [5,6], with which to date we can do less many things because the field is very new, but what we can do is nore natural and is incredibly interesting conceptually.

[1] https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/da9fdef5e00f40dfd500bfa356c61ce6bad1b559/sympy/utilities/iterables.py#L6

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory

[5] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory

[6] https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `cartes`

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import cartes

print list(cartes('CW', 'csv'))
# >>> [('C', 'c'), ('C', 's'), ('C', 'v'), ('W', 'c'), ('W', 's'), ('W', 'v')]

print [''.join(x) for x in list(cartes('CW', 'csv'))]
# >>> ['Cc', 'Cs', 'Cv', 'Wc', 'Ws', 'Wv']

print len(list(cartes('CW', 'csv')))
# >>> 6
```